# Problem with proof enviroment

Tags: proof-package

I have a problem with the proof enviroment.
I'm writing my thesis in german, so the name for the proof enviroment should be Beweis and when I look online everybody says it will do that automatically.
But in my case it doesn't it always says  Proof: .
The other Problem is it doesn't set an end of proof symbol which it should also do automatically.
I tried making an new enviroment called {bew} but that doesn't help either
I hope somebody can help me.
Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,final]{amsbook}
%Sprache
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%Zeichensatz
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%PDF Integrierung
\usepackage{pdfpages}
%Formatierung
\usepackage[left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
%Mathepackages
\usepackage{amsfonts,amstext,amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,mathrsfs}
%Algorithmen
\usepackage{algorithm, program}
\usepackage{physics}
%diverses
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
%Theoreme und Gleichungen
\numberwithin{equation}{chapter}
\numberwithin{figure}{chapter}
\newtheorem{prop}{Satz}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{korro}{Korollar}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\floatname{algorithm}{Algorithmus}
\newenvironment{bew}{\begin{proof}[Beweis]\end{proof}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Test 1
\end{proof}
\begin{proof}{Beweis}
Test 2
\end{proof}
\begin{bew}
Test 3
\end{bew}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @barbarabeeton Sadly that doesn't solve the Problem after including that line the problem still exists

Comment: @egreg -- hmmm.  looked very thoroughly, but didn't find with grep in all language packages in the babel area.  but since you've found the problem, deleting my comment.

Answer (score 1):

The `program` package is the culprit:

```
925 %% \proof macro for theorems and lemmas:
926 \def\proof{\normalshape{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\par\addvspace\medskipamount
927                         \noindent{\bf Proof: }}\ignorespaces}
```

(line numbers added for reference). It's of course a silly definition, but it overrides the one given by `amsthm`. The package also redefines `\qed` and `\qedsymbol`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{program}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
xyz
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I comment out `\usepackage{program}`, I get the expected result:

[image]

with the tombstone at the far end, omitted for getting a well sized picture.

However, you can't simply switch the order of packages, assuming you *really* need `program`.

What you can do is as follows (example reduced to a minimum):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{amsthm}
% save \proof, \qed and \qedsymbol
\let\amsthmproof\proof
\let\amsthmqed\qed
\let\amsthmqedsymbol\qedsymbol
% load program
\usepackage{program}
% revert
\let\proof\amsthmproof
\let\qed\amsthmqed
\let\qedsymbol\amsthmqedsymbol

\begin{document}

\begin{proof}
xyz
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Loading `amsthm` with `amsart` or `amsbook` is not required, because these classes use their own version, but it is important in case you decide to change document class.

As far as I can tell, all language definition files provided with `babel` feature a localization of `\proofname`; here's the output of a `grep` search:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-albanian/albanian.ldf:65:  \def\proofname{V\"ertetim}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bahasa/bahasai.ldf:106:  \def\proofname{Bukti}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bahasa/bahasam.ldf:109:  \def\proofname{Bukti}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-basque/basque.ldf:75:  \def\proofname{Frogapena}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-belarusian/belarusianb.ldf:172:    \def\proofname{Доказ}%  [amsthm]
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-belarusian/belarusianb.ldf:236:    \def\proofname{Доказ}%  [amsthm]
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-belarusian/belarusianb.ldf:292:    \def\proofname{\CYRD\cyro\cyrk\cyra\cyrz}%  [amsthm]
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-belarusian/belarusianb.ldf:343:    \def\proofname{\CYRD\cyro\cyrk\cyra\cyrz}%  [amsthm]
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bosnian/bosnian.ldf:65:  \def\proofname{Dokaz}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-breton/breton.ldf:74:  \def\proofname{Proof}%  <-- needs translation
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bulgarian/bulgarian.ldf:190:  \def\proofname{%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bulgarian/bulgarian.ldf:219:  \SetString\proofname{Доказателство}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-bulgarian/bulgarian.ldf:267:  \SetString\proofname{%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-catalan/catalan.ldf:77:  \def\proofname{Demostraci\'o}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-croatian/croatian.ldf:71:  \def\proofname{Dokaz}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-czech/czech.ldf:103:  \def\proofname{D\r{u}kaz}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-danish/danish.ldf:72:  \def\proofname{Bevis}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-dutch/dutch.ldf:84:        \def\proofname{Bew"ys}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-dutch/dutch.ldf:123:    \def\proofname{Bewys}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-english/english.ldf:133:  \def\proofname{Proof}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-esperanto/esperanto.ldf:72:  \def\proofname{Pruvo}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-estonian/estonian.ldf:76:  \def\proofname{T\~oestus}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-finnish/finnish.ldf:71:  \def\proofname{Todistus}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf:806:   \SetString{\proofname}{Démonstration}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-french/frenchb.ldf:831:   \SetString{\proofname}{D\'emonstration}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-friulan/friulan.ldf:56:    \def\proofname{Dimostrazion}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-galician/galician.ldf:106:  \def\proofname{Demostraci\'on}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-georgian/georgiancaps.tex:35:    \def\proofname{დამტკიცება}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-georgian/georgiancaps.tex:60:    \def\proofname{\geod\geoa\geom\geot\geok\geoi\geoc\geoe\geob\geoa}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-georgian/georgiancaps.tex:83:    \def\proofnamecap{\GEOD\GEOA\GEOM\GEOT\GEOK\GEOI\GEOC\GEOE\GEOB\GEOA}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/germanb.ldf:90:  \def\proofname{Beweis}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-german/ngermanb.ldf:68:  \def\proofname{Beweis}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-greek/greek.ldf:166:  \def\proofname{\textAlpha\textpi\acctonos\textomicron
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-greek/greek.ldf:181:  \def\proofname{\accpsili\textAlpha\textpi\acctonos\textomicron
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-greek/greek.ldf:220:  \def\proofname{\accpsili\textAlpha\textpi\acctonos\textomicron\textdelta\textepsilon
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hebrew/hebrew.ldf:106:  \def\proofname{\@ensure@R{\hebhe\hebvav\hebkaf\hebhet\hebhe}}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-hungarian/magyar.ldf:1598:  \def\proofname{Bizony\'\i t\'as}% AMS-\LaTeX
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-icelandic/icelandic.ldf:77:  \SetString{\proofname}{Sönnun}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-icelandic/icelandic.ldf:104:  \SetString{\proofname}{S\"{o}nnun}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-interlingua/interlingua.ldf:72:  \def\proofname{Prova}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-irish/irish.ldf:72:  \def\proofname{Cruth\'unas}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-italian/italian.ldf:48:  \def\proofname{Dimostrazione}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-kurmanji/kurmanji.ldf:76: \def\proofname{Del{\^\i}l}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-latin/latin.ldf:74:  \def\proofname{Demonstratio}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-macedonian/macedonian.ldf:199:    \def\proofname{%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-norsk/norsk.ldf:75:    \def\proofname{Bevis}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-norsk/norsk.ldf:101:    \def\proofname{Bevis}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-occitan/occitan.ldf:45:   \def\proofname{Demostracion}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-piedmontese/piedmontese.ldf:49:    \def\proofname{Dimostrassion}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-polish/polish.ldf:74:  \def\proofname{Dow\'od}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.ldf:102:    \def\proofname{Demonstra\c{c}\~ao}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-portuges/portuges.ldf:134:    \def\proofname{Demonstra\c{c}\~ao}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-romanian/romanian.ldf:74:  \def\proofname{Demonstra\c{t}ie} %
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-romansh/romansh.ldf:25:  \def\proofname{Demonstraziun}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-russian/russianb.ldf:174:    \def\proofname{Доказательство}%  [amsthm]
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-russian/russianb.ldf:240:    \def\proofname{Доказательство}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-russian/russianb.ldf:317:    \def\proofname{{\cyr\CYRD\cyro\cyrk\cyra\cyrz\cyra\cyrt
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-russian/russianb.ldf:390:    \def\proofname{{\cyr\CYRD\cyro\cyrk\cyra\cyrz\cyra\cyrt
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-samin/samin.ldf:71:  \def\proofname{Duo\dj{}a\v stus}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-scottish/scottish.ldf:71:  \def\proofname{Proof}%    <-- needs translation
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-serbian/serbian.ldf:65:  \def\proofname{Dokaz}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-serbianc/serbianc.ldf:59:  \def\proofname{\CYRD\cyro\cyrk\cyra\cyrz}%{Доказ}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-slovak/slovak.ldf:106:  \def\proofname{D\^okaz}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-slovenian/slovene.ldf:71:  \def\proofname{Dokaz}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-sorbian/lsorbian.ldf:82:  \def\proofname{Proof}%  <-- needs translation
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-sorbian/usorbian.ldf:82:  \def\proofname{Proof}%  <-- needs translation
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanglish/spanglish.ldf:63:  \def\proofname{Demostraci\'on}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.ldf:131:  \SetString{\proofname}{Demostración}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-spanish/spanish.ldf:158:  \SetString{\proofname}{Demostraci\'{o}n}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-swedish/swedish.ldf:71:  \def\proofname{Bevis}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-thai/thai.ldf:128:  \def\proofname{\thaiPhoPhan\thaiSaraI%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-turkish/turkish.ldf:72:  \def\proofname{Kan\i t}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-turkish/turkish.ldf:104:  \SetString\proofname{Kanıt}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-turkish/turkish.ldf:144:  \SetString\proofname{Kan\i t}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-ukrainian/ukraineb.ldf:166:  \def\proofname{{\cyr\CYRD\cyro\cyrv\cyre\cyrd\cyre\cyrn\cyrn\cyrya}}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-vietnamese/vietnamese.ldf:98:  \SetString{\proofname}{Chứng minh}
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-vietnamese/vietnamese.ldf:137:  \SetString{\proofname}{Ch\'\uhorn ng minh}%
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-welsh/welsh.ldf:74:  \SetString{\proofname}{Prawf}
```

Comment: Thank you very much ! That solved the problem. I had some problems with the program package before. Seems like the package is the cause for a lot of conflict. Next time i will try to avoid it.